# How much gold and elixir can be stolen when raiding other players?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was wondering what's the maximum amount of loot that can be stolen while raiding a player or while being raided by another player.

If I have 500k Gold and 600k Elixir, would that mean that they can steal all of my loot? If not, what's the percentage or maximum amount of loot that can be taken?

Comment: Also do not forget that players with a lower TH level can get a little more loot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Until you reach Town Hall 5, 20% from your gold/elixir can be stolen from the storages. The cap for this is 200k. From TH6 and onwards, this percentage drops by 2% for each TH level. From TH7 and above the cap increases with 50k for each TH level.

So for clarity and completeness (and no calculations):

```
TH Level    % Available to be Stolen    Cap    Storage Amount to Reach Cap
1-5         20%                         200k   1.000M
6           18%                         200k   1.1111M
7           16%                         250k   1.5625M
8           14%                         300k   2.1428M
9           12%                         350k   2.9167M
10          10%                         400k   4.0000M
```

Comment: What about elixir collectors and the castle? How much can be stolen from these?

Comment: Afaik you can loose 50% from the collectors, without a cap. Not sure though

Comment: What about dark elixir?

Answer (score 7):

Source is [here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids)

`TH Level    G/E Storages1   G/E Collectors1 DE Storage2     DE Collectors2   CC3
TH 1 - 5    20%, 200K cap   50%             None            None            10%
TH6         18%, 200K cap   50%             None            None            9%
TH7         16%, 250K cap   50%             6%, 2K cap      None            8%
TH8         14%, 300K cap   50%             6%, 2K cap      75%             7%
TH9         12%, 350K cap   50%             5%, 2.5K cap    75%             6%
TH10        10%, 400K cap   50%             4%, 3K cap      75%             5%`

<sup>1</sup>G/E is Gold/Elixir
<sup>2</sup>DE is Dark Elixir
<sup>3</sup>CC is Clan Castle
-[NOTES]-
1. [I use the term "Collector" loosely, it means collector, mine, and drill to their respective resource]
2. [Collector loot is only capped by how much the collector can hold]

Answer (score 0):

I'm only answering to combine the 2 answers, and add drill percentages

Read Mathias711's answer for available storage loot, available collector loot is 50% (for elixir collectors and gold mines), and 75% for dark elixir drills. This is confirmed [here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids)

> "The percentage of Gold and Elixir that can be stolen from mines and collectors is 50% and is capped only by the storage capacity of the resource collector."

> "The percentage of Dark Elixir that can be stolen from drills is 75% and is capped only by the storage capacity of the drill."