# How much Gold and Mana is actually at risk when you are attacked?

Tags: castle-clash

I've noticed that when I am attacked while offline and I lose 100%, I don't lose all of my gold and mana.

I have a tendency to get a little nervous if I have 8 hours left in a worker's job and I have high reserves of gold and mana laying around.  This makes me want to spend some of my gems on either a shield or to just finish the job early so I can spend my currency on the next job.

What determines how much of my gold and mana is at risk to an attacking player?

Comment: Just a note that this is tagged "Castle Clash" and not "Clash of Clans" - we have a question & answer for this already for Clash of Clans, I believe, but not for this game.

Comment: @agent86 I believe this question is what you are referring to: [How much gold and elixir can be stolen when raiding other players?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/175300/12653).  I know both games use the same game engine, but I don't know if they are using the same algorithm on this feature.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I was just pointing out to folks who might think this is a duplicate that it's actually about a different game.  You're fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

25% if from random raids and 5% if from player ranking raids.

That said, it is highly advisable to actually not put much effort in defense. You will get an 10 hour shield if someone 100% you - at a 25% loss. If someone 50% you you would be open to attacks again in 2 hours.

Buying decorations is also a good way to save resources temporarily - but you take a 50% loss when selling the decorations. That said, each upgrade at higher level usually take weeks and you have enough time to stockpile decorations. If not, check if you have a guild mate who has resource overflow problems.